# How to unit test capacitor plugin function calls (Ionic 5)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, capacitor, ionic5, capacitor-plugin

I have a function that specifically uses a plugin called @capacitor/keyboard, so I want to know if it is possible to test the call to some function of the plugin. The problem I have is that the plugin does not work for the web and it is throwing me that error. My function is this:

```
dismissModal() {
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      Keyboard.hide();
      this.modalController.dismiss();
    } else {
      this.modalController.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

I managed to mock up the platform so that the ios platform throws me and be able to test that part, but I don't know how to avoid the error

```
Error: "Keyboard" plugin is not implemented on web
```